# UIButton setTitle forState Not Working

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uibutton, settext

I'm trying to set the text of a UIButton on a new view when a "Next" button is pressed from a previous view. I have set the IBOutlet correctly and I've looked all over for answers to this but it just isn't working at all.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
- (IBAction)computeQuiz:(id)sender
{  
    [fiveFootUniversalResults setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)jumpT10ResultsView:(id)sender
{       
    NSString *nibFileToLoad = @"JumpT10Results";

    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    if([device userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        nibFileToLoad = [nibFileToLoad stringByAppendingString:@"-iPad"];
    }

    JumpmasterPathfinderViewController *nextView = [[JumpmasterPathfinderViewController    alloc] initWithNibName:nibFileToLoad bundle:nil];

    // Modal view controller
    nextView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:nextView animated:YES];

    [nextView release];

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageViewWidth, imageViewHeight + 44.0)];
}
```

These actions are both connected to a button on a previous view. The view loads fine and everything, the only problem is the text WILL NOT change on the button. I'm 100% sure I have the IBOutlets set correctly I just don't know what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that your Action is set? Put a break point in and verify.

Comment: *I'm 100% sure I have the IBOutlets set correctly*, I hope IBActions are connected correctly too?

Comment: The next view shows up and I have placed NSLogs in my computeQuiz action that show up. The actions are getting called.

Comment: In this case something is wrong with `fiveFootUniversalResults`. is this roundedRect button, does it has image?

Comment: At first I had it as a custom button. Then, since nothing was working, I deleted the button and created a new default roundedRect button and attached the IBOutlet to it. Still nothing.

Comment: Do you invoke the computeQuiz: method before or after the view appears?

Comment: Can you debug this with this code if(fiveFootUnivarsalResults) NSLog(@"button exists"); else NSLog(@"btn does not exists");

Comment: How many buttons are you using & which button title you are trying to change?

Comment: @Link Did you ever get this working? I'm running into the exact same problem.

Comment: Could it be iOS 7.1 ? I'm having strange behavior too since iOS 7.1. Need to set both Normal and Selected values. Prior to 7.1, setting only Normal was enough as a default value for all states... Ooops, sorry, just saw it was posted in 2011...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's not working because IB sets `attributedTitle` instead of `title`.

Try this instead:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [self.myButton attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSMutableAttributedString *mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedTitle];
[mas.mutableString setString:@"New Text"];

[self.myButton setAttributedTitle:mas forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or, alternatively:

```
[self.myButton setAttributedTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton setTitle:@"New Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

(The second option won't preserve your formatting.)

Comment: Still not sure why this is not marked the correct answer after 4 Years!

Comment: Feeling dumb that I had to reach this to figure it out, but saved me probably hours of debugging.

Answer (score 3):

try this code....

```
UIButton *backbtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 68, 38)];
[backbtn setTitle:@"Your string" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[backbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:backbtn];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
- (IBAction)computeQuiz:(id)sender
```

method in the

```
- (IBAction)jumpT10ResultsView:(id)sender
```

method rather then calling simultaneously on button click even as simultaneous as in below code, call of method me result in no allocation of fiveFootUniversalResults button object.

```
- (IBAction)computeQuiz:(id)sender
{  
    [fiveFootUniversalResults setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)jumpT10ResultsView:(id)sender
{       
    NSString *nibFileToLoad = @"JumpT10Results";

    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    if([device userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        nibFileToLoad = [nibFileToLoad stringByAppendingString:@"-iPad"];
    }
    JumpmasterPathfinderViewController *nextView = [[JumpmasterPathfinderViewController    alloc] initWithNibName:nibFileToLoad bundle:nil];

    // Modal view controller
    nextView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:nextView animated:YES];

    [nextView release];

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageViewWidth, imageViewHeight + 44.0)];
    [self computeQuiz:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you forget to use the `@synthesize` on the button or variables related to it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the link below helped me when I had the same problem. It allowed me to save all of the attributes in a Dictionary. I created a new attributed string with different text but same attributes, which then I added to the button that I wanted changed. Hope this helps.

[change the text of an attributed UILabel without losing the formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17139059/1435948)

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
[fiveFootUniversalResults setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[fiveFootUniversalResults setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Maybe the background color is the same as the title color. You will not see anything when you writing on black paper with a black pen. Try to set the background color or the title color before calling setTitle.