# MvvmCross binding of text resets font and color

Tags: ios, user-interface, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working on the `iOS` part of a `Xamarin` project and am using the `XCode` interface designer for the `UI`. For the `data-binding` of the `interface` elements we are using `MvvmCross` and now I'm facing the following issue:

I'm binding the text/label of an `UITextView` and a `UIButton` and that works fine. However, the `font` I've setup for these elements in the interface designer is reset if I apply the binding. (Both `font-type` and `font-color` are reset to the default font and color.) If I remove the binding, then I see font and color on the mobile device as configured in the designer. I'm using the following lines to setup the binding:

```
this.CreateBinding(this.theText).For("Text")
    .To((theViewModel vm) => vm.TextSource)
    .WithConversion(new MvxLanguageConverter(), "theText")
    .Apply();

this.CreateBinding(this.theButton)
    .To((theViewModel vm) => vm.theButtonCommand)
    .Apply();

this.CreateBinding(this.theButton).For("Title")
    .To((theViewModel vm) => vm.TextSource)
    .WithConversion(new MvxLanguageConverter(), "theButton")
    .Apply();
```

Is there a way to set this up so that `font` and `color` are preserved? If not I can setup these elements in code, but I prefer to do the design in the designer as much as possible.

Thanks! Olaf

PS. see comments, this is apparently not related to data-binding using MvvmCross. However, the proposed solutions in the other post basically suggest to make a new attributed string using the existing attributes and I don't see how you would do this using binding.

Comment: If you remove the binding and just set the `Text` in code like `this.theText.Text = "Hello";` do you see the same font/color reset?

Comment: My guess is that somehow you using attributedText in Interface Builder - similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488069/changing-uilabel-text-but-keeping-the-rest-of-the-attributes - you should be able to set the properties on the UILabel and then use non-attributed text instead

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, you're probably right, if I change the Text property directly (without binding) the font and color also get lost. So it looks like the design uses attributed text. (Which I find strange, as I've setup the view to use plain text.) I'll do some further research on attributed versus non-attributed text, meanwhile if anyone knows how to circumvent this 'feature'... ;-)